# Type mismatch : 'instrev'

Tags: vbscript

I am getting error like Type mismatch : 'instrev' in below vbscript.

I am trying to rename all excel filed stroed in M:\New folder with MMDDYYYY timestamp appended before extension

Like Test.xls to Test06152013.xls

i am trying to get file names without extension & seems getting error in that logic..I am also trying not get my vbscript renamed itself..appreciate your inputs

```
set oFso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
sDirectorypath = "M:\New folder"
rename_files(sDirectorypath)

sub rename_files(folder)
  set oFolder = oFso.getfolder(folder)
  for each oFile in oFolder.files
    pos = instrev(oFile, ".") -1
   if pos > 0 then oFile = Left(oFile, InStRev(1, oFile, ".") - 1)
    new_name = oFile & replace(FormatDateTime(now,2),"/","") & "." & oFso.GetExtensionName(oFile)
    wscript.echo "renaming " & oFile & " => " & new_name
    errResult = oFso.MoveFile(oFile, new_name)
  next
  for each oSubFolder in oFolder.subfolders
    rename_files(oSubFolder)
  next
end sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The name of the function is `InStrRev`, not `InStRev`.